# How to achieve cross-platform Intellij IDEA `.iml` file with platform-dependent libraries?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, iml

While working across multiple OS, what is preferable way to use libraries in IDEA project?

The .iml file has libraries from Maven listed, some platform dependent:

```xml
...
    <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.openjfx:javafx-controls:17.0.0.1" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.openjfx:javafx-controls:linux:17.0.0.1" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:17.0.0.1" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:linux:17.0.0.1" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.openjfx:javafx-base:17.0.0.1" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.openjfx:javafx-base:linux:17.0.0.1" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.openjfx:javafx-fxml:17.0.0.1" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.openjfx:javafx-fxml:linux:17.0.0.1" level="project" />
...
```

Trying to boot it up on Windows those get overwritten with Windows related versions of those libraries:

```xml
...
    <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.openjfx:javafx-controls:17.0.0.1" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.openjfx:javafx-controls:win:17.0.0.1" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:17.0.0.1" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:win:17.0.0.1" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.openjfx:javafx-base:17.0.0.1" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.openjfx:javafx-base:win:17.0.0.1" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.openjfx:javafx-fxml:17.0.0.1" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.openjfx:javafx-fxml:win:17.0.0.1" level="project" />
...
```

... which I don't think will stay the same for back on Linux/MacOS.

How to work with that? Adding it to `.gitignore` seems bad idea...

Comment: The iml file should only base on dependencies managed by the project pom.xml file(s) so there is no need to check it into a repo.

Answer (score 0):

Use Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Importing | **Store generated project files externally** option.

Don't commit project files for the external build model based projects (Maven/Gradle/SBT).

See also [this FAQ](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839).